# How to extract dynamic substrings with multiples occurences within a variable

Tags: powershell

Learning Powershell with a challenge : 
I am doing a GUI in Powershell-ISE (on a windows server) to avoid typing commands all the time. The goal is to display some informations based on encrypted files that I receive from a unix server. 
So far I am able to display the content of these files in a huge labelbox, but I have difficulties to parse it. 
Later I would need to format that output into a more readable table, instead of a line, but since I am already struggling with the parsing, I keep it for later in another post.
I guess this is a slightly different case from the other posts I have read about "simple" string extraction, or the official doc on -match and $matches. And if I use regex patterns, I always end up with the whole line or nothing (pattern is hard to define since there are many words before and after the targets).
 Also when I use similar codes found in the posts, it is always easier on a pure string, but here my variable contains the input ($Myinput), probably with hidden characters like \n at the end of some values that I am trying to catch (files are from unix, and there, a cat command display it correctly with new lines.. [and no I may not do this script on the unix servers, I am stuck with that windows server with basic powershell components]).
To summarize, I am stuck between posts a little too simple and other posts too advanced for me to understand.
I would appreciate if you can help me to unblock my logic, I will re-post below with the progress.
A. The variable contains something like this :

> This file contains 2 people First name: Group1 Creation date: 23-Jul-2010 word : word word word : word word In since: Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 2004 until: Mon Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 2011 word word word ******************************************* First name: word.word Creation date: 23-Jul-2020  word name : word word word word : word word word from: Fri Nov 02 01:00:00 CET 2010  until: Wed Jan 01 00:59:59 CET 2011 ******************************************* First name: word.word  Creation date: 30-Jun-2020 word: word word word word name : word word word from: Tue Jun 30 11:14:33 CEST 2010     until: Mon Sep 28 11:14:33 CEST 2021 *******************************************

note : it is like a tree with a group on the top and persons below it. A group or a person is an entry.
note : I need to catch the First names and dates for each entries.
B. What I have tried (not all trials here, it would be too long) :
I catch only the number of people and the First names, at the end I would need also "from" and "until".
For the moment I keep them all in arrays by type but I suppose it would be better to use arrays by "people" (?)

```
    #I take the number of people
    $people = ([regex]::matches($Myinput,"\d+") | %{$_.value})
    $labelOutputBox.AppendText("Number of entries: " + $people[0])
    #result not optimized as I get all the digits from that input, and display only the first occurence
    
    #method1 for names
    ([regex]::matches($Myinput,"First name:\s(?<FirstNames>.*)\sCreation date") | %{$_.value})
    $labelOutputBox.AppendText("1/ FirstNames: ")
    $labelOutputBox.AppendText($matches['FirstNames'])
    # result empty
      
    #method2 for names
    $SearchStart="First name: "
    $SearchEnd="Creation"
    $Myinput -match "(?s)$SearchStart(?<content>.*)$SearchEnd"
    $result=$matches['content']
    $labelOutputBox.AppendText("2/ FirstNames: ")
    $labelOutputBox.AppendText($result)
    #result empty, this is where I think a hidden character before the $SearchEnd
```

note: I also dont understand the $matches array, when using <content> , how can I display several "first names" since I can't index it, I tried also <content>[0] nor <content1> <content2> ... 
The more I try the more I am confused.
 I also tried to divide the problem into smaller problems to ease up the process but then it doesnt reflect the real thing, having sometimes different behaviours.
What is wrong with my logic ? and search patterns ?
Should I re-think the way I am treating this matter ? I mean if I take the problems in another angle, by people and foreach people... then I am stuck with too many results in the same person/name for example, and the same results for the next person.
Apologies if this is a bit long but as you can see, divide it and loose the big picture.
Thank you in advance. Any comment is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Some basic information about some of the techniques you are using:

- The syntax `(?<Name>something)` is for creating a named capture group. Here the capture group name is `Name` and it is applied to the match `something`.

  - For accessing each capture group match, you can use the syntax:

    - `[regex]::Matches('something','(?<MyName>something)').Groups | Where Name -eq 'MyName' | Foreach-Object { $_.Value }`
- When using `[regex]::Matches()`, a collection of `Match` objects will be returned if a match is found. Each object can be accessed using an index starting with 0, e.g. `[regex]::Matches()[0]` for the first object or `[regex]::Matches()[3]` for the fourth object.
- `[regex]::Match()` returns a collection of one `Match` object. It will only return the first match found taking into account all of your capture groups. So if you have 2 capture groups, it will return capture group 0, 1, and 2 (0 is the entire match).

  - For example `[regex]::Match('111112111121112','1(2)')`, only matches `12` (capture group 0) and `2` (capture group 1) once yielding one `Match` object. `[regex]::Matches` would return 3 `Match` objects.
- The hierarchy of properties is `Match` Objects -> `Groups` -> `Name`,`Value`. So this means you will have to iterate over the `Match` Objects, then over the `Groups`.
- **`$matches` is an automatic variable. It is updated when the `-match` operator is used against a single string and a successful match is found.** Then you can retrieve `$matches`, `$matches.capturegroup`, etc. **If no match is found, it will retain its current value, i.e. it will not be updated when no match is found!**
- `.*` is a greedy match of any characters. `.*?` is a lazy (ungreedy) match of any characters. To summarize the difference, greedy match will continue matching as long as possible. The lazy match will stop matching as soon as possible.

  - `'11121112' -match '\d*2'` will match `11121112` but `'11121112' -match '\d*?2'` will match `1112`
- **`-match` returns `True` or `False` when used against a single string. It will return the matching items when used against a collection.** To suppress the output use a `null` mechanism like `$null = 'something' -match 'something'`, `'something' -match 'something' | Out-Null`, or `[void]('something' -match 'something')`
- `(?s)` is a mode modifier. The syntax is `(?modifierflag)`. `s` is single-line. Any matches after the modifier apply the modifier. The advantage of `s` is that the `.` character will match newline characters (carriage return and line feed). So if you have a string with newline characters as line breaks, it may be necessary if you want to span your match across lines.

---

For any of these examples to work, it is assumed that `$MyInput` is one single string.

**Using `[regex]::Matches()`:**

```
[regex]::matches($Myinput,'First name:\s(?<FirstNames>.*?)\sCreation date') | Foreach-Object {
    ($_.Groups | Where Name -eq 'FirstNames').Value # Your capture group values
}
```

**Using `$matches`:**

```
$null = $Myinput -match "(?s)$SearchStart(?<content>.*)$SearchEnd"
# If the above found a match, then the following will contain the content capture group
$matches.content
```